# Has anyone successfully run a MoveNet model using tflite in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use MoveNet in Flutter using tflite. If anyone has experience with it or example with the implementation, an example would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully implemented MoveNet singlepose lightning model with tflite_flutter on my Flutter application. You can refer to this repo I made: https://github.com/AGRapista/FitnessInstructor The code you should be interested in is in lib/test.dart